# Default OpenGL lighting in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

How can I light a scene normally using Opengl, and then manipulate the final result using a fragment shader?
Because now it seams, I have to implement lighting myself.
So is it possible to use and manipulate the standard opengl lighting using glsl?

Comment: It's easier to reimplement the fixed pipeline than you might think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here:

https://github.com/mojocorp/ShaderGen

The program will generate the fixed-pipeline shaders for you. But, as Bartek says, the difficulty often lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

No. When you use a shader, you are forced to reimplement lighting from the ground up. However, there's a lot of shaders out there that emulate fixed function pipeline behaviour. I'd recommend taking one of those as your starting point.